# Next Permutation in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve the next permutation question in java but 1/3 test case fails..

Q. A permutation of an array of integers is an arrangement of its members into a sequence or linear order.

For example, for arr = [1,2,3], the following are all the permutations of arr: [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1].
The next permutation of an array of integers is the next lexicographically greater permutation of its integer. More formally, if all the permutations of the array are sorted in one container according to their lexicographical order, then the next permutation of that array is the permutation that follows it in the sorted container. If such arrangement is not possible, the array must be rearranged as the lowest possible order (i.e., sorted in ascending order).

For example, the next permutation of arr = [1,2,3] is [1,3,2].
Similarly, the next permutation of arr = [2,3,1] is [3,1,2].
While the next permutation of arr = [3,2,1] is [1,2,3] because [3,2,1] does not have a lexicographical larger rearrangement.
Given an array of integers nums, find the next permutation of nums.

The replacement must be in place and use only constant extra memory.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3]
Output: [1,3,2]
Example 2:

Input: nums = [3,2,1]
Output: [1,2,3]
Example 3:

Input: nums = [1,1,5]
Output: [1,5,1]

My Code:-

```
class Solution {
    public void nextPermutation(int[] nums) {
        int ind=1;
        int n= nums.length;
        for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
            if(nums[i]<nums[i+1]){
                ind=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        if (ind==-1){
            reverse(nums,i+1,n-1);
        }
        }

        for(int j=n-1;j>ind;j--){
            if(nums[j]>nums[ind]){
                swap(nums,j,ind);
                break;
            }
        }

        reverse(nums,0,n-1);

        for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
            System.out.println(nums[k]);
        }
    }
    public static void swap(int n[],int i, int j){
        int temp=n[i];
        n[i]=n[j];
        n[j]=temp;
    }
    public static void reverse(int n[],int i, int j){
        while(i<j){
            swap(n,i,j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

---

the driver code just accepts the input and calls the function..

What mistake am I making?

my failed test case:-

Input
nums =
[1,2,3]

Stdout
2
3
1

Output
[2,3,1]

Expected
[1,3,2]

Comment: For reference, the source of the problem is  [LeetCode 31](https://leetcode.com/problems/next-permutation/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be missing the step where you reverse the subarray from index "i+1" to the end of the array. This step is essential to ensure you get the next lexicographically greater permutation.

To fix the issue, make sure to add the reverse operation in the function, as shown in the correct implementation above. After adding the reverse step, your function should give the correct output for the given test case and other cases as well.

I solved this way:

```java
class Solution {
    public static void nextPermutation(int[] nums) {
        int i = nums.length - 2;
        while (i >= 0 && nums[i] >= nums[i + 1]) {
            i--;
        }

        if (i >= 0) {
            int j = nums.length - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && nums[j] <= nums[i]) {
                j--;
            }

            swap(nums, i, j);
        }

        reverse(nums, i + 1);
        
        printArray(nums);
    }

    private static void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j) {
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp;
    }

    private static void reverse(int[] nums, int start) {
        int i = start;
        int j = nums.length - 1;
        while (i < j) {
            swap(nums, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    private static void printArray(int[] nums) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(nums[i]);
            if (i != nums.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

Check this out: [LeetCode31 Full Explanation](https://leetcode.com/problems/next-permutation/solutions/3473399/beats-100-full-explanation-in-steps/)